# Building to Replace old version of app with new app version causes app to crash!! reason?

Tags: iphone

I have a game project which runs very fine in device in both **debug** and **release** mode. I have had two versions of it. Old version and new version with more (later i have added) features, and the bundle id, version for both are same. When I build older version, with no previously installed **"myGame"** app. It builds fine and runs fine and vice versa if I build new one first.

But the app crashes when I build new version one with old app already installed in ipod touch, and vice versa if I build old version with new app already installed. The console message looks like follows:

```
 /* Old version installed first and build new version */

Running…
gdb-arm-apple-darwin(3441) malloc: *** error for object 0x4601e0: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 6791.
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 6791.
The program being debugged is not being run.
The program being debugged is not being run.
gdb-arm-apple-darwin(3441) malloc: *** error for object 0x42a7d0: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

/* New version installed first in device then build old version */ 

Running…
gdb-arm-apple-darwin(4195) malloc: *** error for object 0x45e710: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 7079.
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 7079.
The program being debugged is not being run.
The program being debugged is not being run.
```

I can also solve this issue by simply deleting the previously installed app from device. But I want to know the root cause of this crash and I am also afraid if I had my new version app in appStore, It would be very inconvenient to ask user to delete old version first to use new version.

So, please help me to get through this situation. Thanks to any any kind of information.

mysticBoy59

PS: I used the same old version of app and added the features to make new version. Doesn't new one supposed to replace old one easily? As we go on adding features and build and test !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I found out the way to solve my issue, I am explaining a little about it. Normally when we search solution for "The program being debugged is not being run" we just simply delete our older (existing) app in the device and do a new build which seems to work fine.

But the crash, yes of course there is some issue within it which I ignored first. The actual problem was that there was slight product name change in the build settings -> Packaging. 
As i have to mention, this game project was done by me and my friend, he had have little change on the **Product Name** (included white space) when he was doing this programming part (I guess accidentally).

This causes the conflict in **Product Name** within the new and old app version causing crash. Now it works fine. So any of you people ever encounter it, you need check these first. Because most of games are big projects and number of developers are involved in it. So, can cause these actions sometime.

Any way thanks for all who read it. And go going... :)

Comment: Thanks - that saved me hours of trying to figure it out... (newbie - can't vote u up)

Anyway, does anyone know if there is a way around it? I had to change the product name (Capitalization, space) - does this mean my users will fail to update?

Comment: Hey Dan, felt good when I saw it helped you. I guess to update an existing app in iTunes you need to have same product name as previous version. If you changed your product name to different (Space, capitalization), it will fail to update the existing app and install your app as new app (without replacing older version of your app). You need to very careful on these since you can't say your customer to delete previous app before updating to new one. Best of Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would say check the data you are saving to the device first. It is possible that the old version is writing something to the phones memory that is being read by the new version and causing it to crash.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, anyway I found out my solution as I looked my app's settings closely. It helped :)